# How to match javawebstart.version property with Java version?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

Our application is concerned by an Oracle bug on Java Web Start that occurred since Java 6u17 until Java 7u10 (bug ID [6957028](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6957028)).
This is why I want to warn my users if they use a version that will cause them troubles.

So I use the following code to get Java Web Start version:

```
String jws_version = System.getProperty("javawebstart.version");
```

The problem is, that the resulting string makes sense for Java 6, for instance for Java 6u07 is returns `javaws-1.6.0_07`, but somehow with Java 7 it stops making sense. For instance with the new Java 7u10, I get the following version: `javaws-10.10.2.18`.

How can I match this string with the standard Java version? It can't find any documentation on it.

Thanks!

Comment: You are probably better off to [specify a JRE version](http://pscode.org/jws/version.html) for the app. that does not have the bug.

Comment: Actually the JRE version can be forced in the JNLP file, but it's always the latest version that is installed and enabled on your computer that will be used to download the files and launch them with Java Web Start. You can check that in the Java console, both Java Web Start and Java JRE versions are displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I got it, but it's purely empirical!

For Java **1.7.0_25-b17**, the associated Java Web Start version is **10.25.2.17**

So the Java Web Start version is build like this, for *Java 7*:

- 10
- version number
- 2
- build number